# Как переместить только одну точку из множества в SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Пишу SVG + анимация, и столкнулся с такой задачей,-  нужно анимировать только одну точку из множества в координатах SVG(чтобы эта точка плавно изменяла свое местоположение с привязкой линии от других точек).
Например:

```
d="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z" //чтобы плавно переместилась в
d="M10,10 L123,10 L20,20 z"
```

Как это можно сделать только кодом? Без сторонних программ типа Иллюстратора

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анимируется атрибут `d` патча. 
Подставляется первое значение и финальное положение, через точку с запятой

`values="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z;M10,10 L123,10 L20,20z;M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z"`

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid red;">
 <path id="pth1" d="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z" fill="greenyellow" stroke="gray">
  <animate
  attributeName="d"
  begin="svg1.click"
  dur="2s"
  values="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z;M10,10 L123,10 L20,20z"
  fill="freeze"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

**Туда, обратно**

Подставляется в `values` три значения: стартовое;финальное;стартовое

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="border:1px solid red;">
 <path id="pth1" d="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z" fill="greenyellow" stroke="gray">
  <animate
  attributeName="d"
  begin="svg1.click"
  dur="4s"
  values="M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z;M10,10 L123,10 L20,20z;M10,10 L20,10 L20,20 z"
  fill="freeze"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

В атрибут `values` можно подставить сколько угодно промежуточных значений патча,
 **главное следить, чтобы количество контрольных точек было одинаково** у всех промежуточных значений